# "by the time" vs. "when" in a particular sentence

Tags: conjunctions

> The sun will be setting by the time I get home.

> The sun will be setting when I get home.

What is the precise difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

"when/by the time + clause" can mean the same. Often "by the time + clause" has the sense of "when finally" as in

> By the time we came home we were tired and exhausted.